# Pushing AMI ID's to SSM inline bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ami, ssm

I'm trying to use a local shell processor script at the end of our Packer build that gets the latest AMI ID and then pushes this to a specific SSM param.

So far I can get the latest AMI without issue doing

`AWS_PROFILE=myprofile AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --filters "Name=name,Values=my-eks-*" --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images,&CreationDate))[:1].{id:ImageId,date:CreationDate}' --output json | grep "ami-"`

The above code successfully prints the latest AMI I want to push to SSM. I'm just having trouble thinking of a way to get this output successfully to SSM within the same script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would store the amiid in variable which you would use in other aws cli command. Eg.

```sh
ami_id=$(AWS_PROFILE=myprofile AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --filters "Name=name,Values=my-eks-*" --query 'reverse(sort_by(Images,&CreationDate))[:1].{id:ImageId,date:CreationDate}' --output json | grep "ami-")
```

and then in some other command (just some example how to reference `ami_id`):

```sh
aws cli --image="${ami_id}"
```